# Saving map to more than one location at same time

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

Is there a setting where when saving a map document it will automatically save to the pc hard drive and a removable hard drive at once, or do I have to save them separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using shutil? it will copy the mxd file to a destination.

```
    import shutil
    shutil.copy2('/dir/file.ext', '/new/dir/newname.ext')
```

there is also the [saveACopy](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000000n000000) from Arcpy

```
mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Project\Output\\" + df.name + ".mxd")
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy if you use mxd.saveACopy command (my example is for CURRENT document to four folder)

```
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Project\Output\Zero_Folder\\" + df.name + ".mxd")
    mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Project\Output\Second_Folder\\" + df.name + ".mxd")
    mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Project\Output\Third_Folder\\" + df.name + ".mxd")
    mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Project\Output\Fourth_Folder\\" + df.name + ".mxd")
```